# Connection refused when trying to use components.iframe in streamlit

Tags: python, streamlit

I'm trying to display some graphs from different websites for my `streamlit` webpage.

But any time I try to create it, it repsonds `website_url refused to connect`.

My source code is the following:

```py
import streamlit as st
import streamlit.components.v1 as components

components.iframe(website_url, width=1000, height=600)
```

Comment: Did your try visiting the site manually to make sure the it is an active url?

Comment: Of course I checked